# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at popup.js:4:42" error from Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build a Chrome extension. What is the error in the syntax of my eventlistener? Because I think this is what the problem is, as it seems that it is not how the *poup.js* script is specified in my *popup.html*. It is not the variables of the buttons, and I don't know what the issue is.

This is the *popup.js* script:

```javascript
// Add event listener for the 'change' event on the file input
document.getElementById('convert-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Get the file input element
    let input = document.getElementById('file-input');
    let file = input.files[0];
    let pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
    let jsPDF = window['jspdf'];

    //let convertButton = document.getElementById('convert-button');

    if(file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
        //convertButton.innerHTML = "Convert to PDF";
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            // Convert the image to pdf and save it
            let pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(e.target.result, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
            pdf.save("image.pdf");
            // Show success message
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "File Downloaded";
            // Add download functionality
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: pdf.output('bloburl'),
                filename: 'image.pdf',
                conflictAction: 'uniquify'
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        document.getElementById('download-button').disabled = false;
    }
    else if(file.type === "application/pdf") {
        //convertButton.innerHTML = "Convert to Image";
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            // Convert the PDF document to an image and save it
            pdfjsLib.getDocument(e.target.result).promise.then(pdf => {
                pdf.getPage(1).then(page => {
                    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    let viewport = page.getViewport({scale:1});
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;
                    page.render({canvasContext: ctx, viewport: viewport}).then(() => {
                        let img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
                        document.location.href = img;
                        // Show success message
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "File Downloaded";
                        // Add download functionality
                        chrome.downloads.download({
                            url: img,
                            filename: 'image.jpg',
                            conflictAction: 'uniquify'
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        document.getElementById('download-button').disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        // Show error message
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Invalid file type";
    }
});

document.getElementById('download-button').addEventListener('click', () => {

    // Check if a file has been converted and is ready for download
    if(document.getElementById("status").innerHTML === "File Downloaded") {
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: pdf.output('bloburl'),
            filename: 'image.pdf',
            conflictAction: 'uniquify'
        });
        document.getElementById('download-button').disabled = false;
    }
});
```

This is the *popup.html* file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="path-to-stylesheet/style.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Frontpage Image Converter</h1>
    <p>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="file-input"
        accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .webp, .pdf"
      />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="convert-button">Convert</button>
      <button id="download-button" disabled>Download</button>
    </p>
    <div id="status" class="status"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the *manifest.json* file:

```javascript
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Frontpage Image Converter",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "downloads",
      "*://*/*"
  ],
  "incognito": "split",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
      "popup.html",
      "popup.js",
      "path-to-stylesheet/style.css",
      "path-to-jspdf.js",
      "pdf.js"
  ]
}
```

This is the *style.css* file:

```css
/* Add some general styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 400px;
}

/* Style the header */
h1 {
  color: #2ECC71;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Style the file input */
#file-input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Style the convert buttons */
button {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Style the status div */
#status {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #2ECC71;
}

/* Style the status message when the file is being converted */
#status.converting {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #AAA;
}

/* Style the status message when the file has been converted */
#status.converted {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2ECC71;
}
```

I am expecting the "convert" and "download" button to work. They both don't, and I saw this error when I opened devtools in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at popup.js:4:42
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Add `defer` attribute to the script tags or move the script tags to the end of the html.

Comment: This is used as an example in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422686/code-blocks-surrounded-by-triple-backtick-then-single-backtick).